# Postfix setting reply-to field to sender

Tags: email, postfix, regular-expressions

I would like to set the reply-to field to the sender of the mail if the recipient matches some addresses. I know I could do a regular expression like this to do this

`/^(To|Cc):.*foo@bar.com/ PREPEND Reply-To: bla@example.com`

But that would be static, is there a way to set the sender of the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html you could use Perl Syntax for text replacement e.g.

> /^(To|Cc):.*foo@bar.com/ PREPEND Reply-To: ${1}

The puzzle I've left to you is to look up the Perl RE Syntax to retrieve only the email as match.

---

Update:
In your case it's this RegExp:

> /^(To|Cc):\s*(\w+@\w+.\w{2,4})/ PREPEND Reply-To: ${2}

Comment: OK that works but if I use ${1} I get to@ as reply to address, ideas?